# MAC address for DHCP when using bridge with 2 NICs?

Tags: dhcp, bridge

I have a Ubuntu system with 2 NICs where I want to create a bridge `br0` and bind both NICs to that bridge using the `bridge_ports eth0 eth1` option.

I also want to configure the bridge to get an IP address from the local DHCP server.

I think I know how to do this, but I wonder which MAC address(es) will the bridge send out when requesting IP settings from the DHCP server? The MAC address of eht0, eth1, both?

Thanks,
Carsten

Comment: I'd suspect its the first in the order you name them when creating the bridge, or there is a command to designate/override.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `brctl` command used to set up the bridge creates a virtual interface that shows up in `ifconfig`. The default address is the interface with the lowest MAC address. Thus, a NIC with a mac starting with 00:50 will be picked over one starting with 00:6f. It may be possible to change the MAC address by way of `ifconfig`, but you may need to turn off Spanning Tree first.